# Two limits with unknown functions $f,g$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

If $$\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{f(x)-1}{\sin(x)}}=2$$ and $$\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{g(x)-1}{\sin(x)}}=3$$ then find $$\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{f(x)\cdot{g(x)}-1}{\sin(x)}}$$ and $$\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{x\cdot{f(x)}-g(x)\cdot{\sin(x)}-x+\sin(x)}{\sin^2(x)}}$$
My first question is if $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}{\frac{f(x)\cdot{g(x)}-1}{\sin(x)}}=5$ and if, in order to find the $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}{\frac{x\cdot{f(x)}-g(x)\cdot{\sin(x)}-x+\sin(x)}{\sin^2(x)}}$, I must factor with $x$ and $\sin(x)$ respectively and then  divide with $\sin(x)$

Comment: Common functions such as $\sin$, $\log$, $\sqrt{~}$, etc. can be denoted respectively as `\sin`, `\log`, `\sqrt{}`, etc.

Comment: Do $[ \ ]$ braces have special meaning or is it just to group things?

Comment: Can we assume $f$ and $g$ to be differentiable? In that case you can try L'Hopital.

Comment: I'm confused. What is your "first question"? Where is that if $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)g(x)-1}{\sin x}=5$ from??

Comment: @leos Kotrop:If you are looking for tricky method ...I tell you a very simple trick !?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}{[\frac{f(x)\cdot{g(x)}-1}{\sin(x)}]}=\\\lim_{x\to 0}{[\frac{f(x)\cdot{g(x)}-1-g(x)+g(x)}{\sin(x)}]}=\\\lim_{x\to 0}{[\frac{(f(x)-1){g(x)}+g(x)-1}{\sin(x)}]}$$divide into cases
$$=\\\lim_{x\to 0}{[\frac{(f(x)-1){g(x)}}{\sin(x)}]}+\lim_{x\to 0}{[\frac{g(x)-1}{\sin(x)}]}=\\\underbrace{\lim_{x\to 0}{g(x)}}_{w.r.t \space  \lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{g(x)-1}{\sin(x)}}=3 \implies g(0) \to 1}\lim_{x\to 0}{[\frac{(f(x)-1)}{\sin(x)}]}+\lim_{x\to 0}{[\frac{g(x)-1}{\sin(x)}]}=1.2+3=5$$ for the second one

$$\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{x\cdot{f(x)}-g(x)\cdot{\sin(x)}-x+\sin(x)}{\sin^2(x)}}=\\\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{x({f(x)}-1)-(g(x)-1){\sin(x)}}{\sin^2(x)}}=\\
\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{x({f(x)}-1)}{\sin^2(x)}}-\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{(g(x)-1){\sin(x)}}{\sin^2(x)}}=\\\text{simplify   and you know },\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1\\
\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{({f(x)}-1)}{\sin(x)}\cdot\frac{x}{\sin x}}-\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{(g(x)-1)}{\sin(x)}}=\\2.1-3=-1$$

Comment: Yeah much better, no need for l'Hopital's rule here.

Comment: I think you need to comment on why $g(0)=1$. Are we assuming continuity?

Comment: @Miguel :I fixed it . thank you for notice

Comment: Really nice answer. Exactly the kind I like (uses only algebra of limits) +1

Answer (score 2):

Observe

$$f(x)g(x)-1 = (f(x)-1)(g(x)-1) +(f(x)-1)+ (g(x)-1).$$

Dividing by $\sin x$ gives

$$\frac{f(x)g(x)-1}{\sin x} = \sin x \cdot\frac{(f(x)-1)}{\sin x}\cdot \frac{(g(x)-1)}{\sin x} +\frac{(f(x)-1)+ (g(x)-1)}{\sin x}.$$

The limit of the left side is thus $0\cdot 2\cdot 3 + 2 + 3 = 5.$

Answer (score 1):

Redefine $f(0)=g(0)=1$. (The values of $f(0)$ and $g(0)$ are irrelevant for the limits, so you can redefine the values without changing the limit. This redefinition assures that $f,g$ are continuous at zero.)

Noting that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$, we see that the above means that $f'(0)=2$ and $g'(0)=3$. This is because:

$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{\sin x}\cdot\frac{\sin x}{x}$$

The limit of the left side is by definition $f'(0)$, the limit of the right is $2\cdot 1$.

Now:

$$\frac{f(x)g(x)-1}{\sin x}=\frac{f(x)g(x)-f(0)g(0)}{x}\cdot \frac{x}{\sin x}
$$
The limit requested is the equal to $$(fg)'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)g(x)-f(0)g(0)}{x}$$

But by the product rule of derivatives, this is $f(0)g'(0)+f'(0)g(0)=1\cdot 3+2\cdot 1=5$.

Comment: Are you sure that $f',g'$ exist ?

Comment: @Khosrotash They don't exist except at zero, and this is because $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)-1}{\sin x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-1}{x}$. But you might have to redefine $f(0)$ to ensure that $f$ is continuous at $0$. I've added that note above.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sorry, I took continuity for granted.

Comment: @Miguel Yeah, I made that assumption too in my initial write-up.